# Pybrain's neural network not learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pybrain

I have built neural network using pybrain.
What am trying to do is to create a dictionary that can work with typing errors.

I built the dataset that is normalized, created network, trained it with my dataset until convergence.

Now when I test it, my results get all random. I tryed some new inputs, and all original inputs that were used to train network. Nothing came up with right solution.

Thanks in advance!

```
'''
Created on Dec 8, 2016

@author:
'''


from pybrain.structure import FeedForwardNetwork
from pybrain.structure import LinearLayer, SigmoidLayer
from pybrain.structure import FullConnection
from pybrain.datasets import SupervisedDataSet
from pybrain.supervised.trainers import BackpropTrainer
from pybrain.tools.shortcuts import buildNetwork
from pybrain.supervised.trainers import RPropMinusTrainer

num_of_definitions = 7

real_input = [["rouge", "red", "rot"],
              ["jelov", "yellow", "yelov"],
              ["wit", "white", "wajt"],
              ["green", "grun", "groen"],
              ["bleu,", "blue", "blau"],
              ["color", "couleur", "kleur"],
              ["brown", "bruin", "braun"]]

real_output = [["crvena"], ["zuta"], ["bijela"], 
               ["zelena"], ["plava"], ["boja"], ["smeda"]]


def normalize_polje(polje):
    novo_polje = [[]]
    for i in range(0, num_of_definitions):
        for j in range(0, len(polje[0])):
            novo_polje[i].append(normalize_string(polje[i][j]))
        novo_polje.append([])
    novo_polje.pop()
    return novo_polje


def normalize_string(st):
    d = 0.0

    for i in range(0, len(st)):
        d += ord(st[i]) / 122.0
    d /= len(st)
    return d


def output_appr(d):

    diff = 1.0
    t_diff = 0.0

    for i in range(0, len(output)):

        t_diff = abs(output[i][0] - d)

        if t_diff < diff:
            diff = t_diff
            index = i

    return real_output[index][0]


def input_appr(d):

    diff = 1.0
    index1 = 0
    index2 = 0

    for i in range(0, len(iinput)):
        for j in range(0, len(iinput[i])):
            t_diff = abs(iinput[i][j] - d)
            if t_diff < diff:
                diff = t_diff
                index1 = i
                index2 = j
    return real_input[index1][index2]


iinput = normalize_polje(real_input)
output = normalize_polje(real_output)

n = FeedForwardNetwork()

inLayer = LinearLayer(3)
hiddenLayer = SigmoidLayer(3)
outLayer = LinearLayer(1)

n.addInputModule(inLayer)
n.addModule(hiddenLayer)
n.addOutputModule(outLayer)

in_to_hidden = FullConnection(inLayer, hiddenLayer)
hidden_to_out = FullConnection(hiddenLayer, outLayer)

n.addConnection(in_to_hidden)
n.addConnection(hidden_to_out)

n.sortModules()

ds = SupervisedDataSet(3, 1)

for i in range(0, len(iinput)):
    ds.addSample(iinput[i], output[i])

trainer = BackpropTrainer(n, ds)
trainer.train()

epoch = 1

while True:
    error = trainer.train()
    print ("Epoch #" + str(epoch) + " Error: " + str(error))
    epoch += 1
    if epoch > 1000:
        print "No Solution found!"
        break
    if error < 0.001:
        print "Solution found!"
        break
    trainer.trainUntilConvergence()


for innput, expectedOutput in ds:
    print innput
    outputt = n.activate(innput)
    print outputt
    print "Input: {}, Got: {}".format(input_appr(innput[0]), output_appr(outputt))

print ""
tst_str = "redd"
novi = normalize_string(tst_str)
print tst_str, novi
lista = []
lista.append(novi)
lista.append(novi)
lista.append(novi)
print n.activate(lista)
print output_appr(n.activate(lista))
'''print n
print iinput
print output
print("dataset:" + str(len(ds)))
for inpt, target in ds:
   print inpt, target'''
```

Comment: Please post the code in the question itself (rather than just linking to it on an external site).

Comment: hey, code is around 150 lines, should i paste them all? it's gonna look funny. I can paste some parts of the code, but since the code is working, i am not sure what to paste

Comment: See [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for details on how to select which code to show. Basically, the goal is for the posted code to be minimal (no longer than is necessary to help us identify the problem), complete (it should contain enough code for us to be able to identify the problem), and verifiable (i.e. someone should be able to verify that it does, in fact, produce the problem). The article I link to gives details on how to do that.

Comment: thanks, il do it now!